# problema con tupla y metodos

Tags: python

```
f=open("INFORMACION.txt","w") #abrir de salida el fichero
for i in range(1,101):
codigo="COD-"+str(i).zfill(3)
alea=random.randrange(0,3000)
fecha=origen_fecha+timedelta(days=alea)
sueldo=random.randrange(1000,9999)
departamento=random.choice(departamentos)
f.write(codigo+" "+str(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))[0:10]+" "+str(sueldo)+ \
        " "+departamento+"\n")
f.close()


#lectura del fichero
def leer_fichero():
f=[]
for linea in open("INFORMACION.txt","r"):
    f.append(linea.rstrip('\n'))
return f
```

No entiendo el significado en `str(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))[0:10]` de `[0:10]`, he buscando por otros lugares pero no encuentro la informacion exacta de esto.

Comment: Basicamente es un recorte de 10 caracteres de la cadena `str(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))`.

Comment: pero por que? se que es una pregunta tonta, pero podrías poner algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por partes

```
str(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))[0:10]
```

`fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")` transforma un dato `date` como imagino que es `fecha` en una cadena con el formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, si los cuentas son exactamente 10 caracteres. Lo siguiente que se hace es redundante `str()` sobre un dato que ya debería ser una cadena, no tienes necesidad de volver a pasarlo a cadena.

Lo que se hace por último `[0:10]` es un `slice` o recorte de una cadena de lo 10 primeros caracteres de izquierda a derecha, que también es redundante por que de por sí la cadena ya tiene 10 caracteres. Por ejemplo:

```
import datetime 
fecha = datetime.date(2019, 3, 4)

print(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
print(str(fecha.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))[0:10])

04/03/2019
04/03/2019
```

Como puedes ver, la salida es la misma. El sentido de hacer el recorte `[0:10]` se me escapa, a veces los programadores agregamos código para asegurarnos ciertas cosas, en este caso que la cadena sea de 10 caracteres, aunque en este ejemplo en particular no pareciera ser necesario.

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió